# Aggregate column based on certain conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I guess I am trying to do a pivot table of some sort but I can't figure it out.
I am trying to check each column for a missing value, then aggegrate the missing values grouping it by PatientID.

Thanks in advance.

| Lab | PatientID | LabTime | Glucose | Protein | Sodium | TestMissing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10am | 23 | 43 |  | Sodium |
| 2 | 1 | 11am | 23 |  | 34 | Protein |
| 3 | 2 | 10am |  | 43 |  | Glucose |
| 4 | 2 | 12am | 23 |  | 23 | Protein |
| 5 | 2 | 1am | 23 | 43 |  | Sodium |

Expected table

| PatientID | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Protein, Sodium |
| 2 | Glucose, Protein, Sodium |

Comment: You are actually looking for string_agg()

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on my comment

```
Select PatientID
      ,NewValue  = string_agg(TestMissing,',')
 From YourTableOrQuery
 Group by PatientID
```

**EDIT <=2016**

```
Select PatientID
      ,NewValue  = stuff((Select  ',' +TestMissing From cte Where PatientID=A.PatientID For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From YourTableOrQuery A
 Group by PatientID
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option that will dynamically generate the MISSING value(s)

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VgP1-2lU)**

```
;with cte as ( 
Select Distinct 
       PatientID
      ,[Key]
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (  Select [Key]
                From OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES  ) ) 
                Where [Key] not in ('lab','patientID','LabTime')
                  and Value is null
             ) B
)
Select PatientID
      ,NewValue = string_agg([Key],',')
 From  cte
 Group By PatientID
```

**Results**

```
PatientID   NewValue
1           Protein,Sodium
2           Glucose,Protein,Sodium
```

**EDIT <=2016 Version**

```
;with cte as ( 
Select PatientID
      ,[Key]
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (  Select [Key]
                From OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES  ) ) 
                Where [Key] not in ('lab','patientID','LabTime')
                  and Value is null
             ) B
)
Select PatientID 
      ,NewValue = stuff((Select  ',' +[Key] From cte Where PatientID=A.PatientID For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From  cte A
 Group By PatientID
```

Comment: not sure how to mention you John, but thank you so much. I was going to try it, but it only works for sql server 2017 and up and im still on 2016, trying to get my manager to upgrade it. thanks again!

Comment: @eveningmouse See EDIT.  I added an Stuff/XML Approach